# A working upwork-api financial report call now returns invalid_query

Tags: php, upwork-api, invoice-ninja

I had made a simple APP which automatically creates my upwork invoices to my Invoice ninja setup but lately, upwork side broke. I saw that there were updates and changes on it but after my research, nothing changed in my specific call. After the authorization, I am using the following [call](https://developers.upwork.com/index.html?lang=php#reports_get-financial-reports-for-the-current-users-accounts):

```
$finreports = new \Upwork\API\Routers\Reports\Finance\Accounts($upwork_client);
$freelancerReference = "8009XXX";
$params = array(
    "tq" => "SELECT amount, notes WHERE date >= '2018-06-01' AND date <= '2018-06-30'"
);
$results = $finreports->getOwned($freelancerReference, $params);
echo "<pre>".print_r($results, true)."</pre>";
```

and i am receiving this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[version] => 0.6
[status] => error
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [reason] => invalid_query
                [message] => Internal Server Error
            )

    )
```

The auth seems OK because I can successfully get the response from:

```
$auth->getUserInfo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a pity to hear that your reporting system stopped working correctly. Unfortunately, you use the API which is marked for deprecation. Inherently, the changes are being rolled out, and that seems to be the root of the issue you experience - see the [proper announce](https://developers.upwork.com/api-changelog.html).

Comment: Its weird that this call is mentioned that it will be deprecated in 15/7 and also is still in the [doc](https://screenshots.firefox.com/jdkJTBWJlNe7YSoC/developers.upwork.com). Do you know a way to get those data with another call

Comment: @Alexandros, thank you for the feedback. The documentation is going to be updated shortly.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! So those financial data is no more offered from any other call?

Comment: Unfortunately. As it has alluded above, the mentioned API is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Since mnovozhilov is the author on the Upwork API library files that I've read, it is great to have his confimation that the Accounts API has been deprecated.

Perhaps you can get the information you need through billings.  Just a note that the API documentation says to use:
from upwork.routers.reports import billings

But for the version I have, there is an extra finance folder, so I need to use:
from upwork.routers.reports.finance import billings

I've been checking my paths by looking in File Explorer at the install folder\Lib\site-packages\upwork...., to see where the import files are located.

With your team reference you can use get_by_buyers_team(self, buyer_team_reference, params)

With your company reference you can use get_by_buyers_company(self, buyer_company_reference, params)